# Error on uninstalling / installing VSTO Excel plugin

Tags: .net, excel, plugins, vsto, add-in

I have a problem with VSTO packages. I now, there are many ways to cleanup the download cache, to deinstall the app and much more, but i tried it all and still have the problem.

I deinstalled the ExcelAddIn via the system app "Remove Programs and Features", cleared the download cache via

```
rundll32 dfshim CleanOnlineAppCache
```

and manually removed all files from AppData\Local via

```
rd "%userprofile%\Local Settings\Apps\2.0" /S /Q
rd "%userprofile%\Local Settings\assembly\dl3" /S /Q
```

After that i run the WiseRegistryCleaner to cleanup the registry from all old entries.

But after i finished all steps successfully i still have the problem and get the following error if i want to start the .xlsm (or the vsto) file:

```
All exceptions: System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException: Unable to install this application because an application with the same identity is already installed. To install this application, either modify the manifest version for this application or uninstall the preexisting application.
...
```

What can i do now?

Answer (score 0):

I found out, tha the WiseRegistryCleaner has not found all old registry keys. I searched through the whole windows registry and found some entries for the AddIn. After i deleted this entries the VSTO file worked

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem... how did u find the other entries? can u tell me their adress in Registry plz?